# Trouble using mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` but I think I am not using it correctly. The code below grabs the username and password and runs a query in the database and if it matches it is meant to echo back success.

However, when I print out the row it is empty. What might I be doing wrong?

I am not planing to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` I know how that works. I want to make use of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` in this case.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (empty($email) || empty($pass)) {
      header("Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      $sql = "SELECT idUsers, emailUsers, firstNameUsers, lastNameUsers, pwdUsers, bdayUsers FROM users WHERE emailUsers = ?";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo 'errorme';
        exit();
      }
      else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt ,"s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_Users ,$email_Users, $first_NameUsers, $last_NameUsers, $pass_word, $bday_Users);
        if ($row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          $message = $row["$email"];
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
          $pwdCheck = password_verify($pass, $row['pwdUsers']);
          if ($pwdCheck == false) {
            echo 'wrongpass';
            exit();
          }
          else if($pwdCheck == true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['firstNameUsers'];
            echo 'success';
            exit();
          }
          else {
            echo 'noresults';
            exit();
          }
        }
        else {
          echo 'nouser';
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
}
else {
  header("Location: ../login.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You should really not be using that ancient procedural mysqli stuff for new code. mysqli has an object-oriented interface that is slightly more modern, though many (myself included) would recommend using PDO instead.

Comment: Also please verify what output you're getting from your script with the code provided, e.g. "nouser", "noresults", etc.

Comment: You made use of bind_result, yet, you are not using all the bound variables in your script. [See example 2 in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: I am getting wrongpass...even though the pass is 100% correct (this might be due to the row being empty..). I will take a look at PDO.

Comment: Use these variables that you defined `$id_Users ,$email_Users, $first_NameUsers,...` Not `$row`

Comment: Is it not possible to just get the row number since I am just trying to match the username and password (I just don't know how to use all those varaibles to check the password)? Sorry for all these questions new at php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind the results through `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`, and these are the variables which will hold the values once your results are fetched.

Your `fetch()` function returns a boolean, and not a result (unlike the non-prepared queries).

```
if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
     $message = $email_Users;
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
     $pwdCheck = password_verify($pass, $pass_word);
```

The same goes for any place you attempt to use `$row` - you have to use the variables that are assigned in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` (so `$id_Users` instead of `$row['idUsers']`, `$first_NameUsers` instead of `$row['firstNameUsers']` and so on).

See the documentation for each method for more details.

- [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-result)
- [`mysqli_stmt::fetch()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.fetch)